# Running WinFlash from command line is not interpreting arguments

Tags: windows, command-line, laptop, bios, asus-laptop

I'm trying to flash the BIOS on my ASUS G53SW using the included WinFlash.exe program. However, the battery in it is busted and through some Googling I've discovered that you should be able to run the exe through command prompt with the /f or /forceit argument. Doing that however, returns this error:

CANNOT FIND BIOS FILE: /F or CANNOT FIND BIOS FILE: /forceit

I've cd'd to the directory and am using WinFlash.exe /f, WinFlash /f, WinFlash /forceit and WinFlash.exe /forceit. I've also tried adding in the BIOS file as the first argument like so:

WinFlash.exe C:\Users\Me\Downloads\bios.file /f still to no avail, it just returns that it cannot find the BIOS file at C:\Users\Me\Downloads\bios.file /f

Any help? I can't find any documentation on ASUS WinFlash, and every forum I've found just says that using /f works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **`/nodate`** instead of `/F` or `/forceit`
From a Command Prompt, type something like

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\WinFlash\WinFlash.exe" /nodate
```